# How to fix No matching function Call to ... <unresolved overloaded function type>

Tags: c++, class, pointers, callback, pthreads

I have cut out most of the unnecessary bits of code and abstracted it to get the gist of what I think is going wrong with my code. Hopefully it's not too vague.

I am trying to reverse engineer how some existing DeviceModels are implemented, called DeviceTypeA and DeviceTypeB. I am trying to create a new device model called DeviceTypeC. It registers a callback to an interfaceFacade to handle incoming messages for this particular device. When this class calls the function it hands the information about itself to the interface along with its callback function. From the interface Facade it passes it to a statusManager which is responsible for listening to incoming messages and routing them back to DeviceTypeA to be processed.

DeviceTypes A, B, and C are fairly unique, but interface with this status manager int the same manner. However, when I try to implement the same code logic for, "DeviceTypeC.registerForInterfaceMessages();"
I get the following errors:

```
Error: no matching function for call to 'MyInterface::InterfaceFacade::registerForStatus(int&, int&, void*, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
        processMessageTypeA;

DeviceTypeC::DeviceTypeC.cpp note: candidates are:
In file included from DeviceTypeA.hpp
                from DeviceTypeC.cpp
InterfaceFacade.hpp note: MyInterface::InterfaceFacade::registerForStatus(int,int,void*,StatusManager::RouteC::MessageTypeACallback)
        void registerForStatus

InterfaceFacade.hpp note: no known conversion for argument 4 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'StatusManager::RouteC::MessageTypeACallback {aka void (*)(void*, const boost::shared_ptr<MessageAbstraction::MessageTypeA>&)}'
```

I hope this abstraction isn't too confusing. It really doesn't make a lot of sense why the first two implementations would work (DeviceTypeA and DeviceTypeB), but mine wouldn't using the same code?

```
#include "DeviceTypeA.hpp"

namespace DeviceTypeA {


    DeviceTypeA::DeviceTypeA():m_interfacePtr(new MyInterface::InterfaceFacade(123,321))
    {
        registerForInterfaceMessages();
    };
    ~DeviceTypeA::DeviceTypeA(){};


    DeviceTypeA::registerForInterfaceMessages(){
        m_interfacePtr->registerForInterfaceMessages(123,321,static_cast<void*>(this),processMessageTypeA);
    }

    void DeviceTypeA::processMessageTypeA(void* thisptr, const boost::shared_ptr<MessageAbstraction::MessageTypeA>& msgPtr ){
        reinterpret_cast<DeviceTypeA*>(thisPtr)->processMessageTypeA_Impl(msgPtr);
    }

    void DeviceTypeA::processMessageTypeA_Impl(const boost::shared_ptr<MessageAbstraction::MessageTypeA>& msgPtr){
        //do stuff here
    }

}
```

The interface Facade class passes this along to a status manager

```
    #include "InterfaceFacade.hpp"

    namespace MyInterface {


        InterfaceFacade::InterfaceFacade():m_statusMgrPtr(NULL)
        {
            m_statusMgrPtr = StatusManager::RouteC::instance();
        };
        ~InterfaceFacade::InterfaceFacade(){};



        void InterfaceFacade::registerForStatus(int id, int address, void* ptr, StatusManager::RouteC::MessageTypeACallback callback){
            if(NULL !=m_statusMgrPtr ){
                m_statusMgrPtr->registerForStatus(id,address,ptr,callback);
            }
        }

    }
```

The status manager is then responsible for taking incoming messages and passing it back to the DeviceModelA class so that the method:

```
 void DeviceTypeA::processMessageTypeA_Impl(const boost::shared_ptr<MessageAbstraction::MessageTypeA>& msgPtr)
```

... can process what to do with the incoming message.

```
#include "StatusManager_RouteC.hpp"

namespace StautsManager {


    RouteC::RouteC(){};
    ~RouteC::RouteC(){};



    void RouteC::registerForStatus(int id, int address,void* ptr,MessageTypeACallback callback){
    //do stuff here
    }

    void RouteC::registerForStatus(int id, int address,void* ptr,MessageTypeBCallback callback){
    //do stuff here
    }


}


/*
RouteC.hpp
*/

namespace StatusManager {

class RouteC{
    public:
        RouteC::RouteC();
        ~RouteC::RouteC();

        typedef void (*MessageTypeACallback)(void*, const boost::shared_ptr<MessageAbstraction::MessageTypeA>& msg);
        typedef void (*MessageTypeBCallback)(void*, const boost::shared_ptr<MessageAbstraction::MessageTypeB>& msg);



        void RouteC::registerForStatus(int id, int address,void* ptr,MessageTypeACallback callback){
        //do stuff here
        }

        void RouteC::registerForStatus(int id, int address,void* ptr,MessageTypeBCallback callback){
        //do stuff here
        }
}



}
```

Comment: It's confusing enough for me! Could you include the actual code in your own implementation that causes this error? For now my guess is that it could have something to do with the difference between pointers to functions and pointers to member functions.

Comment: Just came back here to check some old posts. Just wanted to let you know so you weren't left in the dark the whole time. I neglected to look closely at the header files and noticed that it needed to be a static type lol.